# First post different layout

Tags: php, wordpress, formatting, conditional-statements

I need to have a different layout for the first post in every page, but don't know where to start. The code is the following:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div class="row">
<section class="small-12 columns grid-style">
<?php $i = 0; $counter = range(0, 200, 3); ?>

  <?php 
  $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
  $args = array('offset'=> 0, 'paged'=>$paged);
  $all_posts = new WP_Query($args);
  if (have_posts()) :  while($all_posts->have_posts()) : $all_posts->the_post();?>

    <?php if ($i % 3 == 0) { echo '<div class="row journal" data-equal=".post">'; } ?

    <!--Post -->
      <article class="grid-style post" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"
        <div class="post-img">
            <?php get_template_part( 'inc/postformats/grid-style' ); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="post-box">
            <div class="post-title">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echo ShortenText(get_the_title(), 50); ?></a></h2>
            </div>
            <aside class="post_categories">
                                <?php the_category(', '); ?>
            </aside>
            <div class="post-content">
                <?php echo ShortenText(get_the_excerpt(), 170); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
      </article>

    <!--/Post -->

      <?php if (in_array($i + 1, $counter)){ echo '</div>'; }   ?>

  <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <?php theme_pagination($all_posts->max_num_pages, 1, true); ?>
    </div>
  <?php else : ?>
    <p><?php _e( 'Please add posts from your WordPress admin page.', THB_THEME_NAME ); ?></p>
  <?php endif; ?>
</section>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

I need to use a different image size, so I need to output everything inside < ! - - Post - - > again for the first post only.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to include div.row.journal to the first post?
If it's the case try doing this:

*Replace `<?php if ($i % 3 == 0) { echo '<div class="row journal" data-equal=".post">'; } ?` by the following:* (It'll echo it only on the first page, for the first post)

```
<?php
if ($all_posts->current_post == 0 && !is_paged()) {
    echo '<div class="row journal" data-equal=".post">';
}
?>
```

*Doing the same for the closing div by replacing `<?php if (in_array($i + 1, $counter)){ echo '</div>'; }   ?>` by :*

```
<?php
if ($all_posts->current_post == 0 && !is_paged()) {
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi @plop Thanks for your help! that worked great to ad classes to the first post. But what I am trying to do is have a complete different layout and a larger image, so i need to echo everything inside <!--Post --> again but I am having trouble figuring out how to do that with        <?php get_template_part( 'inc/postformats/grid-style' ); ?>

Comment: Why not something like this?

`<?php
if ($all_posts->current_post == 0 && !is_paged()) {
    get_template_part( 'inc/postformats/other-layout-style' );
} else {
    get_template_part( 'inc/postformats/grid-style' );
}
?>`

And duplicate the file _inc/postformats/grid-style.php_ into _inc/postformats/other-layout-style.php_

Then by editing other-layout-style.php you'll be able to do the layout your want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a counter and ask with if...else... inside the loop

```
$post_counter = 1;
while (start_loop):

   if ($post_counter == 1){
       echo "<div id='1'></div>";
   else:
       echo "<div id='2'></div>";

   $post_counter += 1;

//end loop
```

I think that should help you.

Comment: Thanks @Tobi Klostermair didnt really work,probably because I don't know PHP. But got me thinking about $post_counter=1 / What I actually had to do was use $post_count=0 and then $post_counter++; and when it reached 1 output the html I wanted, but now I have 2 copies of the first post... Any ideas on how I can just have 1 first post? I will answer myself so you can see the code I am using now

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I have now, I was able to output the HTML for the first post, and a different one for ALL the posts, but I am getting 2 first posts. One using the first layout and the second using the second layout

```html
<?php
   /*
   Template Name: Blog - Grid Style
   */
   ?>
   <?php get_header(); ?>
   <div class="row">
   <section class="small-12 columns grid-style">
    <?php $i = 0; $counter = range(0, 200, 3); ?>

      <?php 
      $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
      $args = array('offset'=> 0, 'paged'=>$paged);
      $all_posts = new WP_Query($args);
      $post_counter = 0;
      if (have_posts()) :  while($all_posts->have_posts()) : $all_posts->the_post();   $post_counter++;?>

        <?php if ($i % 3 == 0) { echo '<div class="row journal" data-equal=".post">'; } ?>



        <?php if ($post_counter == 1){ ?>

        <!--Layout Post 1-->
        <div class="row">
          <article class="grid-style post small-9 small-centered column" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <div class="post-img">
                <?php get_template_part( 'inc/postformats/grid-style' ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="post-box">
                <div class="post-title">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echo ShortenText(get_the_title(), 50); ?></a>1</h2>
                </div>
                <aside class="post_categories">
                                    <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                </aside>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php echo ShortenText(get_the_excerpt(), 170); ?>
                </div>
            </div>


          </article>
         </div> 
        <!--/Layout Post 1-->

        <?php } ?>


        <!--Other Posts -->
        <div class="row">
          <article class="grid-style post small-9 small-centered column" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

            <div class="post-img">
                <?php get_template_part( 'inc/postformats/grid-style' ); ?>
            </div>

            <div class="post-box">
                <div class="post-title">
                    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php echo ShortenText(get_the_title(), 50); ?></a></h2>
                </div>
                <aside class="post_categories">
                                    <?php the_category(', '); ?>
                </aside>
                <div class="post-content">
                    <?php echo ShortenText(get_the_excerpt(), 170); ?>
                </div>
            </div>


          </article>
         </div> 
        <!--/Other Posts -->




          <?php if (in_array($i + 1, $counter)){ echo '</div>'; }   ?>


      <?php $i++; endwhile; ?>

        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <?php theme_pagination($all_posts->max_num_pages, 1, true); ?>
        </div>
      <?php else : ?>
        <p><?php _e( 'Please add posts from your WordPress admin page.', THB_THEME_NAME ); ?></p>
      <?php endif; ?>
   </section>
   </div>
   <?php get_footer(); ?>
```